# Iterate through a subdirectory and delete all files not matching the database entry

Tags: php, mysql, subdirectory

I have been working on a site that relies heavily on images, and so I want to implement functions that clean up if anything is wrong, either in the database or the subdirectory that I'm storing them in.  My function that deletes database entries if the image isn't in the subdirectory works, but my function that deletes images in a subdirectory if they aren't on the database doesn't seem to work.  Here is my code (assuming that there is an entry called "location" on a table called "images" on the MySQL database, there is a subdirectory called "images", all images have a jpg extension, and all uploaded images are given the same key in the database as on the subdirectory):

```
foreach(glob("images/*.*") as $entry)
    {   
        if (!mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE location = '$entry'")))
        {
            if (preg_match("/jpg/", $entry))
            {
                unlink ($entry);
            }   
        }
    }
```

I did debugging and the entry in the subdirectory matched the entry on the database, but despite the fact that they are equal, the SQL query was returning empty results.

Comment: Sorry, bobby tables is here: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: hakre - I don't think this is meant to be run on the web in which case SQL injection isn't that big of a deal but I agree with Mike that PDO is a much better option.

Comment: @Mike - I stated that PDO is a better option for a variety of reasons. But there's no sense in rewriting working code to fix imaginary vulnerabilities either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glob` returns the entry with the path so it will be like `images/foo.jpg`. If it's stored in the database with just the filename that's why it's not matching.

Comment: So you're saying I should add the "images/" to the database entry?

Comment: No I'm saying you should parse "images/" part out of it.

Comment: look into `readdir` instead of `glob`. There's an example in the documentation: http://php.net/readdir

Answer (score 1):

Unless the code you have presented isn't the actual code, my guess would be that you aren't passing an absolute path to `unlink();`. You are only passing a relative path ("images/test.jpeg" for example) and the script cannot find that file.

Comment: No, because the entries don't seem to match.  I was able to unlink the file perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you provide some sample rows of your database?

Comment: Ah, then @Cfreak's answer is probably correct. You could use `basename($entry)` to get the filename from the path.